# calling function from actionscript (.as) file for button in mxml

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Can anyone help me in this regard?

I have Actinscript file in which I have defined a function like below:

**actionScript.as (file name)**

```
import mx.controls.Alert;


public function abc():void{

     Alert.show("Inside abc(): My Button Clicked");

}
```

Now I have a button in mxml and I am calling the above function in my buttion "click" attribute like below.

**Importing script in mxml:**

```
<mx:Script source="actionScript.as" />
```

**Using function:**

```
<mx:Button id="button1" label="My Button" click="abc()"/>
```

Can any one help me? Is there anything else I need to do or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: What's not working here? Is your function not getting called when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

create a new project and make these 2 files

test.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script source="includes/test.as"/>
    <mx:Button label="Alert Test" click="abc()" />
</mx:Application>
```

src/includes/test.as

```
// ActionScript file
import mx.controls.Alert;
public function abc():void{
    Alert.show("Inside abc(): My Button Clicked");
}
```

works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

wrap up your .as file in a package and class reference. instantiate the class in your MXML and call the function using instantiated class.

```
var Class1:Something = new Something();
Class1.abc();
```